# ImageMagick No decode delegate for this image format

Tags: php, ios, imagemagick, imagick

I work under windows and wamp server.

this is my PHP code with Imagick

```
$imagick = new Imagick($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $this->_name);
```

where `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$this->_name` displays :

> D:/Sources/my_project/public/media/2/9/1/05201502/55450e1b6543a05201502_9.PNG

I checked that image and it does exist in the folder.

But Imagick throws an exception  :

> Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate
>   for this image format
>   `D:/Sources/my_project/public/media/2/9/1/05201502/55450b10d8ea705201502_9.PNG'
>   @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555' in
>   D:\Sources\my_project\library\project\Image.php on line 225

I looked for a solution, but didn't find any, how can I fix this?? thank you

**Update:** This is the result when I type `convert -version` in the command line :

```
  Version: ImageMagick 6.8.8-4 Q16 x86 2014-01-29 http://www.imagemagick.org
  Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
  Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
  Delegates: bzlib cairo freetype jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr pangocairo \
             png ps rsv g tiff webp xml zlib
```

**update**

This is the phpinfo of imagick.

> ImageMagick number of supported formats:  0
>   ImageMagick supported formats:    no value

Comment: Please add also `phpinfo()` ImageMagick supported image formats.
Also - make sure that file is readable by PHP with `readfile()` or similar function.

Comment: @KalleVolkov, Thank you for the suggestion, I updated ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that your ImageMagick PHP module does not support **any** image formats.

Try to find other ImageMagick installation or install PHP from the scratch.

Also - seems that there is already [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279301/imagemagick-supported-formats-no-value) in SO about that

Comment: Although I didn't solve fully my problem, your answer helped me alot, I think I'm now closer to find a solution.

The problem I think is with the MOD_xxx.dll files, apache looks for them in /bin folder, and I have them in my imagick folder .... anyway, thanks a lot :), I've been struggling with this for more than 2 weeks.

Answer (score 6):

You should run

```
convert -version
```

and report the output. On my system it is

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.0-0 Q16 x86_64 2014-12-06 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype gslib gvc jbig \
                      jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png ps \
                      rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

Does your output include `png` as one of the built-in *'delegates'*?

If not, update your installation, or build from current sources.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, +1 , this is my output

`C:\Users\TAQI>convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.8-4 Q16 x86 2014-01-29 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib cairo freetype jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr pangocairo png ps rsv
g tiff webp xml zlib`

Comment: As you can see, it contains png and jpeg, notice that the problem is not only for png images, but also for jpeg images.

Comment: @SmootQ: Please update your original question with the contents of your comment. It's not much use to have this info in a comment hidden somewhere down south of the page...

Answer (score 4):

Finally I found solution for my windows openserver/nginx/php-fpm installation:

1. Download latest php_imagick distributive for your version of PHP from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/ (e.g. php_imagick-3.4.3-7.1-ts-vc14-x64.zip)
2. Extract only php_imagick.dll from this archive to your "php/ext" folder.
3. Run phpinfo() and check value at line "Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version" (mine was: "ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x64 ...").
4. Now go to http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/ and download correct version of Imagick-*.zip file (mine was: ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc14-x64.zip).
5. Extact this archive and copy all *.dll files from "/bin" folder to yout "php/ext" folder (about 145 files).
6. Restart server and check phpinfo(). ImageMagick now supports about 230+ formats.

Sometimes phpinfo() displays that imagick supports all formats, but php scripts are not respond - in this case double check that you download correct version of Imagick-*.zip for your installations. (ts/nts, VC11/VC14, x64/x86)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, It's been two years since I posted the question , thank you for taking the time to answer, sure there are many others who need as many answers as possible. +1