# installing imagick with PHP+NGINX Windows

Tags: php, nginx, imagick

I have googling, and only found tutorial for APACHE+ PHP http://refreshless.com/blog/imagick-pecl-imagemagick-windows/
i follow the instruction, but I don't know what should I do with "CORE_RL_*" files because I'm running NGINX not Apache.

thanks

Comment: are you running window or linux ?

Comment: see the title, it's windows

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36378764/2358222

make sure to tick the unblock option in the windows properties (step 5).

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by moving the CORE_RL_* files to C:\Windows\System32. They just need to be in any directory that is included in the system variable PATH.