# Cannot load imagick library

Tags: php, apache, laravel, imagick

I have installed the imagick from [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) (ImageMagick-7.0.3-1-Q16-x64-dll) and the dll (TS 32 bit) from [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.1.2/windows). And also copiend the `CORE_RL_*` to the `C:\xampp\apache\bin` BUT still i get the following error when i run the laravel server.

> ERROR: Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
> in Unknown on line 0

Also, I placed dll file in `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll`.

Also, the imagick is shown in the `phpinfo()`.
[image]

And when i use it using laravel i get the following error.
[image]

Comment: Does `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll` actually exist?

Comment: Yes, it is there.

Comment: I've never installed it on windows, can't help you directly. Anyway I know it needs some time to make it work, try to follow these instructions http://stackoverflow.com/a/36378764/1090867

Comment: @phaberest I followed the link you mentioned but I am still getting same error. Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Why don't you use Laravel Homestead with vagrant instead of becoming crazy trying to use Windows as testing environment?

Comment: hey Jamal Abdul Nasir did you fixed it?

Comment: Just make sure you have `Visual C++ Redistributable Package` installed on your computer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170). It solved my issue.

Answer (score 36):

getting Imagick to work on Windows has always been a bit hit and miss as pointed out here is a good guide
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36378764/1090867

But it misses an important point

You do not need to put the binary into the PHP folder!

So here are the steps I follow myself every time I need to do this. This should work for apache, Nginx, or IIS.

### Step 1

find out your php version and setting

[image]

You need to version, Architecture, Compiler and Thread Safety

if Thread Safety is disabled this is **NTS** is enabled it will **TS**

### Step 2

Get and install a copy of ImageMagick and make sure it matches your Architecture, this also needs to be dll.exe rather than the static version.

Regarding Q8 and Q16 I'll leave that to you but both versions will work

[Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

I recommend changing the install directory name to something generic like
`C:\Imagemagick` since I've had some problems in the past with the default directory name with PHP and windows.

Just install but make sure you tick add application path and I normally tick the legacy utils as well.

[image]

Once it's installed go to your environment variables and make sure it is actually in the path. **There is no need to copy anything to your PHP folder**

Just to make sure everything is working open the command line and type `convert --version` you should get a response

### Step 3

This unfortunately is the hard part and can be a bit of trial and error. I've found the following provides the best php_imagick.dll that seems to work 9 times out of 10

http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/

Just pick the version that matches your install.

If this doesn't work then go to php.net and try each version until one works... (start at the latest)

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/

Once you have a php_imagick.dll put it into your `php/ext/` folder

thne locate your `php.ini` file go to the bottom (or whereever your extensions are) and add `extension=php_imagick.dll`

### Step 4

Restart PHP (or your computer) and it should be working if not try a different php_imagick.dll and repeat.

### If the above doesn't work

Then try a slightly older version of Imagick I normally use version 6.8.6-8 Q16.

Please note I've only ever really done this on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, and 2012 R2 all x64 with x86 PHP

If this still doesn't work then you probably need to copy over the `CORE_RL` files into your Imagick directory this normally causes more issues but if you are running out ideas then give it a go

Comment: Your very last sentence did the trick for me ... Copy the CORE_RL files from the archive with the php_imagick.dll directly into the imgagick install folder. It wasn't necessary to overwrite existing DLLs however, only add the ones that were missing.

Comment: O|O:  Enhanced tutorial: http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/349/how-to-install-and-enable-the-imagick-extension-in-xampp-for-windows. Tested in: XAMPP Version 7.1.1, Php 7.1.1, Windows 10 Pro, ImageMagick 6.9.3-7-vc14-x86.zip

Comment: Yup, same here for the last sentence!

Comment: Hell yea, this is a great help! Thank you. Can confirm this is still working.

Answer (score 27):

I just ran into this issue.  Only I'm using PHP on the command line (PHP CLI).  The problem is the dependencies that the main `php_imagick.dll` file has.  PHP will attempt to load the extension but since Windows can't find the `CORE_RL_` DLLs, the extension will fail to load and the error/warning message about being unable to load the DLL will appear.  It helps to know how Windows loads DLLs:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx

It's pretty convoluted but you can see that the reason the Apache `/bin` directory trick works with Apache is that `httpd.exe` is located in that directory.  However, when using PHP CLI, the DLLs need to be located in the same directory as `php.exe`.

If you don't want duplicate DLLs floating around, add the directory containing `php.exe` to the system PATH and plop all the `CORE_RL_` DLLs there.  The PATH is the last thing searched, but it'll work fine.  If you don't want spurious entries in your system PATH, then set the extra PATH information only during startup of Apache.

Comment: thanks, I found this answer is more straight forward. WinNMP requires ALL the .dll and .pdb inside the folder containing php.exe for imagick to work. Then put the php_imagick.dll inside /ext. Always check the php log, they will give you the clue.

Comment: Place the imagick .dlls into the php folder containing php.exe.  You, my friend, deserve a medal.

Comment: Thanks.  I maintain a large number of repos over on GitHub - mostly PHP and C++ projects.  A star or fork isn't exactly a medal but feel free to peruse the list of repos and star/fork away at projects of any interest:  https://github.com/cubiclesoft/

Answer (score 9):

This is because the dependencies are missing. Those who are facing the same error **Unable to load dynamic library `'php_imagick'`**, Please follow the below steps

- Go to https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick choose a stable version and click on the DLL link.
- From the DLL list click the link which, is suitable for your PHP version.
- After downloading the php_imagick zip file, extract it and copy the `php_imagick.dll` file to `C:\xampp\php\ext` folder.
- Extract all DLL files from the php_imagick zip file (**except `php_imagick.dll`**) to the PHP root directory (where you have php.exe). Ex: For XAMPP user `C:\xampp\php` folder.
- Add `extension=php_imagick` to your php.ini file.
- Restart the Apache server.

**Things to keep in mind before choosing from the DLL list.**

1. Check the PHP version.
2. Check the architecture (x64/x86).
3. Check Thread Safety (enabled/disabled).

[image]

**N.B: Above solution is for XAMPP users only.**

Answer (score 0):

I changed php_imagick in php.ini file to php_imagick.dll and it happened

Answer (score -1):

###### Step 1

First you have to **download the Imagick library** according to your **PHP Version** from https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.5.1/windows.

###### Step 2

Then copy and paste `ImageMagickObject.pdb`, `ImageMagickObject.dll`, `LICENSE`, `LICENSE.IMAGEMAGICK`, `php_imagick.dll` and `php_imagick.pdb` into the `C:xampp/php/ext` folder.

###### Step 3

In the `php.ini` file, you have to add:

```ini
extension = extension=php_imagick.dll
```

###### Step 4

You have to extract the `.zip` file of the download from the above link, paste it into the **`C:` drive** and rename the folder to `php_imagick-3-5-1`

###### Step 5

Set environmental variables like:

[image: environmental variables]

Restart you PC and check again.