# Windows PHP Imagick not working

Tags: php, windows

I am trying for 1 days and this php imagick don't work in windows. It shows

```
ImageMagick number of supported formats:    0
ImageMagick supported formats   no value
```

First I went to official php website from here

```
http://windows.php.net/download/
```

And downloaded `VC14 x64 Non Thread Safe (2017-May-09 23:02:49) PHP 7.1.5`

I extracted it into `C:\ProgramData\php` and added it to `PATH variable`.

And from that directory i renamed `php.ini -devlopment` to `php.ini`

And changed `line 738` to `extension_dir = "ext"` so that extensions can be loaded in PHP.

Then php must be working now.
I went to `http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.4.3/`
And downloaded `php_imagick-3.4.3-7.1-nts-vc14-x64.zip`

And from that zip file i extracted `php_imagick.dll` into `C:\ProgramData\php\ext` directory

And also from that zip file I extracted `CORE_RL_*.dll` into `C:\ProgramData\php` folder.

And I added `extension=php_imagick.dll` to `php.ini` file at `line 892`

After that i went to `http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps` 
And downloaded `ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc14-x64.zip` and extracted content of that folder to `C:\ProgramData\ImageMagick` directory. And I added `C:\ProgramData\ImageMagick\bin` to my `path`.

I think I have done all configuration.

But when I create index.php and add `phpinfo()` function to file in desktop and try to run

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

and go to `localhost:8080` in web browser it shows

```
imagick module  enabled
imagick module version  3.4.3
imagick classes Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version   ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x64 2016-03-27 http://www.imagemagick.org
Imagick using ImageMagick library version   ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x64 2016-03-27 http://www.imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright   Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date    2016-03-27
ImageMagick number of supported formats:    0
ImageMagick supported formats   no value
```

Clearly it is not working .Where did I make mistake. Imagik is so painful to install :(

Comment: "Imagik is so painful to install" That is one reason why I do not use it. If you are using it for development I assume it is installed on your server. Why not get the rest of your site working on your localhost and get the Imagick code working on the server? I use Imagemagick through the command line with exec( )

Comment: @Bonzo i guess found the solution you can watch if you are facing . But i agree running exec() would be good :)

Comment: Add the imagick .dlls into the php folder containing php.exe.  Saved my life, this post. Take a look here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48600203/1965718

Answer (score 0):

Recently I found this solution:

I went to `C:\ProgramData\php` and deleted `CORE_*.dll` file which i copied .

I needed to copy that as doing `php -v` was showing error at that time.

and after immediately deleting and rebooting server it showed

```
ImageMagick number of supported formats:    234
```

I don't know what is happening but i am happy it is working

And above steps will work as documentation for other user who are in problem like me :)