# Laravel - Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found

Tags: laravel, imagemagick

Running a new laravel project locally I get this error:

> Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll' -
> The specified module could not be found

The dll exists but I think having read a number of articles this is down to the version of the dll I have. I have tried a few but I still get this error. Is there a way of identifying the version I need?

Version of XAMPP Control Panel: 3.2.3
& php info:

[image]

php_imagick.dll in C:\xampp\php\ext

[image]

Any pointers as to how to resolve this?

Comment: How does `imagick` show up in `phpinfo` if the library can't be loaded?

Comment: @brombeer This is exactly why I am asking the question. The dll exisits (or at least a version of it but I suspect it may be the wrong one). But when I run php artisan serve in VS Code this is the error I get. The project still opens fine, but I would like to get to the bottom of the error if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot load imagick library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609951/cannot-load-imagick-library)