# Cant able to see imagemagick in phpinfo

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm trying to install Imagemagick

I have un comment the link php_imagick.dll in `php.ini` refer screen `1`

[image]

And I have added the `.dll` file in `php/ext` refer screen `2`

[image: Php Imagick]

I have restarted the apache after doing this but its not working

Comment: Are you sure that you use PHP "TS -> Threadsafe" pls try to uncomment the non ts version and restart apache,

Comment: yes i tried that too but no improvement

Comment: any errors in php error.log or Apache error.log??

Comment: let me check it @ArneRie

Comment: getting this error in php error log `[31-Jul-2015 11:21:15 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\Projects\php\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

`

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445493/trying-to-get-imagick-running-on-php-5-4-3-at-windows-x64

Comment: I tired above link but no impovements for me