# Installing php_imagick.dll PHP extension on wampserver 2.2

Tags: php, windows, wamp

I am on Windows 7 on a 32-bit OS.

I installed ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16 from [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) and I was able to run ImageMagick from command line ("convert" command).

Then I downloaded the VC9 version of php_imagick.dll from http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.1.2/windows.

I placed in the PHP extension directory. I tried both NTS and TS however they recommended TS.

Then I made changes to php.ini file but the extension wouldn't load. In apache error log it says:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found. 

in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

I am using wamp server 2.2 which is compiled using VC9 as well. I want to use Imagick functions in PHP scripts.

Any help with fixing this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: You might have not seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28872879/3422447)

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem, here is my configuration:

Windows 8.1 64Bit
PHP 5.4 (Thread Safe)
Apache 2.2

I tried to install the Latest Version of ImageMagick but its fail to load and I solved by installing the following version (6.7.7-5-Q16 32bit) and its worked fine with http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/ImageMagick-6.7.7-5-Q16-windows-dll.exe.

after install download  imagick dll from the link (imagick 3.1.2 Thread Safe )

http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.1.2/windows

after restarted apache and start working

Comment: Yes it works!
Use ImageMagick same as apache/php bit. For example: Apache/PHP 64 bit, use ImageMagick 64 bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try the Q8 version `php_imagick-3.1.2-5.3-ts-vc9-x86.zip`

Yes, it has to be the TS (Thread Safe) version as Apache and PHP are compiled TS in the WAMPServer system.

Also the `php_imagick.dll` is delivered as part of the Imagick download, look in the unzipped file structure for it. Copy that to the `/ext` folder, not the PECL one.

Answer (score -1):

[Running ImageMagick on XAMPP 1.8.3 with Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055786/running-imagemagick-on-xampp-1-8-3-with-windows-7)

Install details copied:

ImageMagick: ImageMagick-6.7.7-5-Q16-windows-dll ([here](http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/multimedia/graphics/ImageMagick/binaries/))

Imagick DLL: PHP 5.5.x version from http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/