# Working version combination of ImageMagick, IMagick and XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, imagemagick, xampp, imagick

I'm trying to get the following working: XAMPP, ImageMagick and IMagick PHP extension. I started with the latest of everything:

```
xampp-win32-1.8.3-2-VC11
ImageMagick-6.8.8-2-Q16-x64-dll
php_imagick-3.1.2-5.5-ts-vc11-x86
```

I then tried different versions of the latter two:

```
ImageMagick-6.8.8-2-Q8-x86-dll, ImageMagick-6.7.7-5-Q16-windows-dll
php_imagick-3.2.0b1-5.4-ts-vc9-x86 (and others)
```

(In all cases the PHP extension is installed as '/php/ext/php_imagick.dll')

But on launching XAMPP Apache I always get one of the following two errors (depending on the dll used):

```
 PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll'
      - The specified module could not be found; or
      - %1 is not a valid win32 application
```

There is lots on the internet about this including this answer [Running ImageMagick on XAMPP 1.8.3 with Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055786/running-imagemagick-on-xampp-1-8-3-with-windows-7), but none consistent and nothing that works for me. I'm starting to think that the versions thing is a red herring and that there is something more subtle at play. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Same problem here. Could you find a solution meanwhile?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed response. My solution in the end was to use Wamp instead of Xampp. The interface is not as nice but it got me running.

Comment: ah ok. thank you! I'll try it. As long as I can have a wamp AND xampp installation on my PC it's fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the errors you received at launching Xampp '%1 is not a valid win32 application', this seems due to a x86 - x64 mixed up. Either by trying to run x64 Imagemagick with Xampp (which is native x86), either/or a wrong PHP extension. 
Iam no expert in PHP, but it's a rule of thumb to use x86 add-ons, modules, extensions etc. for a native x86 app.