# How to get ImageMagick running with XAMPP on Win7?

Tags: php, windows, dll, imagick

I am trying for the whole day but I cannot get my ImageMagick flying with XAMPP on a Win7 machine. I downloaded ImageMagick (for specs see below), downloaded the `php_imagick.dll` from the PECL website and added it to my `php.ini`.

ImageMagick runs smoothly in the command line. But as soon as I start my Apache (by the way, I tried with Windows reboot as well, for sure), I get one of the following error messages (I tried with different DDLs):

> The procedure entry point "php_checkuid_ex" could not be located in the dynamic link library "php5ts.dll"

or

> The procedure entry point "MagickGetImageGravity" could not be located in the dynamic link library "CORE_RL_wand_.dll",

(there has been a third error message where entry point was something with `Draw...Alpha` in `CORE_RL_wand_.dll`.)

Some specs:

- Win7 (x64)
- XAMPP, win32, v1.8.3-2, VC11
- PHP v5.5.6, Compiler: MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
- ImageMagick-6.8.8-5-Q8-x86-dll

(I used to have the ImageMagick Q16/x64, but due to my exhausting research today I read that I should use the x86 variant as XAMPP/Apache are also running on 32bit - so I deinstalled the Q16 and installed the Q8. Unfortunately with no success.)

Anyone can help me figuring out which `php_imagick.dll` I need or any other idea what I have to modify so that this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the [answer to basically the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21084043/1828051) (and same tech spec). I simply had to download an older version of ImageMagick (`ImageMagick-6.7.7-5-Q16-windows-dll`).

(By following the linked answer above you can find a link to that version of ImageMagick and a working `php_imagick.dll`.)

Answer (score 0):

I solve with these: https://github.com/WPN-XM/WPN-XM/issues/222

So I work with:

```
Win7 (x64)
XAMPP, win32, v3.2.1, VC11 with php 5.6.12
```

php_imagick-3.1.2-5.6-ts-vc11-x86
ImageMagick-6.9.2-0-Q16-x64-dll

Comment: Please don't just post a link, it's better to quote the relevant information from that page in your answer.