# Imagick on Windows 8 xampp

Tags: windows-8, xampp, 64-bit, imagick

I want to install imagick on windows 8 64bit, xampp.
I have tried all methods in internet how to solve this problem, but none helped me ( have tried more than 10 methods ).

In all results i get error while launching apache.

- Apache 2.2.21
- PHP 5.3.8
- Windows 8 64

Latest method i have tried: http://w3facility.info/question/how-to-install-imagemagick-for-php5-35-4-on-windows-8-x64/

In case i change to extension=php_imagick_nts.dll error looks like:

> The program can't start because php5.dll is missing...

In case i change to

> The program can't start because CORE_RL_wand_.dll is missing...

Method's suggestion to copy dll's to windows/system32, didn't helped me.

To help you and me, questions you might ask:

> 1. Have you restarted xampp? Yes
> 2. Have you restarted windows? Yes
> 3. Have you added path? Yes
> 4. Does CMD command convert gives proper answer? Yes
> 5. What path you installed Imagick? C:\imagemagick

Errors:
After install ImageMagick-6.8.9-8-Q16-x64-dll.exe

> php_imagick_ts.dll' - %1 is not va valid Wind32 application.

Comment: did you restarted php after copying ?

Comment: Yes, restarted apache, mysql, xampp and windows too. several times.

Comment: did you downloaded the dll's specific to your operating system.i mean the dll's are different for 32 bit of windows and 64 bit

Comment: dll's specified link in the method is not working, so after hour of searching i found this page with downloadable tar.gz - http://afi-forge.afi-sa.fr/projects/opacce/wiki/Wamp_server_+_Image_magick . It says 32 bit ;S . Method's author mentionted it and wrote to copy these dll's to system32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem only by installing latest xampp version (XAMPP Version 1.8.3) and continued the method: [Running ImageMagick on XAMPP 1.8.3 with Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055786/running-imagemagick-on-xampp-1-8-3-with-windows-7)

Install details copied:

- ImageMagick: ImageMagick-6.7.7-5-Q16-windows-dll (available [here](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/))
- Imagick DLL: PHP 5.5.x version from http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/