# How do I install Imagick for PHP in Wamp?

Tags: php, imagick

I tried hard to install the Imagick extension for PHP on Windows. I already downloaded the Imagick installation file via different links many times. But still I did not succeed.

How to install the Imagick extension in Wamp in a proper way?

Comment: Check this out : http://refreshless.com/blog/imagick-pecl-imagemagick-windows/

Comment: check this link, http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php it has description of how to install imagick on different platforms.

Comment: Are there any errors or other messages during the installation?

Comment: I already done it ...but still not get proper result..Thanks ..

Comment: Please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34288143/778719