# Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found

Tags: php, windows, xampp

This is so strange, the module is clearly inside that directory. When I used that directory in file explorer, it found the module. I think it's compatibility issue ? rather than not found ?

I got that dll from here http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.4.1/

Comment: You also have to install ImageMagick. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055786/running-imagemagick-on-xampp-1-8-3-with-windows-7

Comment: I know, I have install, but I lack one step. I am going to post that answer.

Answer (score 11):

Okay, after reading this article, I realized I lack one step of below, I thought, i just have to copy the php_imagick.dll to the ext directory.

copy CORE_RL_* file move into C:\xampp\apache\bin

http://hrt0kmt.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/05/27/170608

Comment: better way - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55967226/how-to-install-imagemagick-php-extension-for-use-on-iis-server-on-windows-server/55967227