# Php 5.6 not load imagick

Tags: php, iis, imagemagick, imagick

PHP (5.6) cannot load the imagick extension on the iis server page. However in console loads correctly.
What could be the reason for this? how to solve it?

Comment: PHP 5.6 is outdated a/f, you should not have that in production use any more anyway.

Comment: First you need to update php 5.6 to newer version such as 7.4.13. You can get it from Web PI. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASf4A.png Then refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55967227/14162739) to install ImageMagick on IIS correctly.