# TYPO3 xampp "Wrong JPEG library version: library is 90, caller expects 80"

Tags: php, xampp, typo3

When working on my Windows local TYPO3 7 environment where ImageMagick is being used I have problems with images. When running the Test setups in the install tool the "Convert image formats to jpg" all fail. When running the same command being used by TYPO3 local I get the following error:

```
identify.exe: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 90, caller expects 80 `C:/xampp/htdocs/www/OTAP/nijmegen.local.alternet.nl/typo3temp/pics/installTool-scale-jpg5806158c60059221619814.jpg' @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/331.
```

Im running the 7.0.9 xampp and have php_gd2.dll enabled in php.ini. In phpinfo() I see the libJPEG Version at "9 compatible". Should this be 8? and how can I change that?

Thanks in regards

Answer (score 0):

I needed ImageMagick to work locally, I use xampp 1.8.3 and when I installed I found an article that suggested to use a very specific version of ImageMagick that is ImageMagick-6.7.7-Q16 to be found maybe [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/releases/) (since the link in the article is not there anymore)...

[this is the article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21084043/5353105) ,its really easy to do, it worked for me and I'm not prepared in this area ...