# How to install current imagick on wamp

Tags: php, wamp, imagick

This is been a real pain I'm trying to install **imagick** for my local dev wamp stack (windows 7).

I understand downloading and installing the relevant **dll.exe** from **imagick**, then I'm supposed to get .dll to place in my php extensions folder and refer to it in .ini.

All the blogs and tutorials refer to links that no longer exist could someone point me in the direction of a matching dll.exe from imagick and the .dll to put in my php extensions folder

Comment: in wamp you have two php.ini files have you made changes to both files ?

Comment: I don't have the relevant from dll.exe from imagick and matching dll.exe as all the tutorials I can find refer to dead links.

Thats the question

Comment: There are some good answers at this [older SO Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942523/step-by-step-instructions-for-installing-imagemagick-on-wamp?answertab=votes#tab-top). Some of the answers are older, and still useful. There are also some newer answers. You can set your sort order to "oldest", then scroll to the bottom, to see answers that may cater to the most recent versions of PHP, Windows, Imagick, or WAMP.