# Unable to install php_imagick.dll on wamp

Tags: php, wamp, imagick

I tried various tutorials online as well steps given on SO answers but nothing worked.

I am using windows 64 bit and m using wamp 2.4 ver and php 5.4.12 
I have tried various combinations of Imagemagik and php_imagick.dll but nothing worked

Please help, its very important for to run it

I am getting the following error

[image]

Comment: Which version of WAMPServer are you running the 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: I searched little more and i was able  to see the tick on imagick extension but it is not showing up on phpinfo()

Comment: Did you install the Thread Safe (TS) version of the DLL

Comment: Actually i tried both ts and nts

Comment: It definitely needs the Thread Safe version

Comment: What version of the php_imagick.dll are you trying to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know we can open php.ini directly from wamp icon shown in tray but in my case it was not opening. So i was manually opening it from C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12
But then i realized that we have to make changes in three files to make it work.
That are:

1. C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini
2. C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\phpForApache.ini
3. C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini

Then I followed the steps given by fsasvari in following link

1. Download ImageMagick: ImageMagick-6.7.7-5-Q16-windows-dll from [here](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/) (other versions did not work for me)
2. Install in C:\imagemagick, on last step check "Add application directory to your system path"
3. Download Imagick DLL: PHP5.5.x version from http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/ (I have 5.5+ version installed on my localhost
4. Copy php_imagick.dll to C:\wamp\bin\php\ext
5. Download PHP 5.5 Thread Safe (TS) x86 version from http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.1.2/windows
6. Copy CORE_RL_* files to C:\wamp\bin\apache\bin\
7. Edit php.ini file in C:\wamp\bin\apache\bin\php.ini, add extension=php_imagick.dll line in extensions section
8. Copy all files from C:\imagemagick\modules\coders and C:\imagemagick\modules\filters to C:\imagemagick to load ImageMagick supported formats
9. Go to Control Panel -> System -> Advanced Settings -> Environment Variables -> New System Variable -> MAGICK_HOME = C:\imagemagick
10. Restart Wamp server and check phpinfo() for imagick plugin
11. If last step does not work, restart Windows

[Answer by fsasvari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28872879)