# How to add more supported formats in ImageMagick?

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, wamp

I have installed extension successfully in my WAMP.
But problem is its shows only 153 supported format.

I need PDF as supported format there. 
please help and let me know how to install extra formats there ?

Below is image from phpinfo.

[image: ImageMagick]

Comment: You will need to install `ghostscript` if you want PDF support.

Comment: @MarkSetchell : Can you explain me or refer me any link for how to do it with ghostscript ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use WAMP. I do know that you will need to install `ghostscript`. Try Googling `ghostscript WAMP imagemagick`. Something like this... http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,137438,137455

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33337866/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell : I will check and try to install it. Thanks for your help and time. I will share, if i get done.