# Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: php, windows, dll, imagemagick, imagick

I am trying to install imagemagick on xampp server on windows OS.

I have downloaded ImageMagick-6.9.8-3-Q8-x64-dll.exe file and extracted into c:/imagemagick,added this path to env variable

I have downloaded php_imagick.dll file and pt into php/ext folder ,added this to env variables too.

I have restarted apache too

When I am trying to  check using phpinfo() , i could not see image magick section over there.

When i type `php -e` on cmd

I am getting `Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

Help.

Comment: You will be unlikely to see an Imagemagick section as it is an external program. Imagick is a php API for Imagemagick and if installed correctly it should show up in in the php.info file. Installing Imagick can be a pain and you want to search for that instead of Imagemagick.

Comment: as @Bonzo said it's a pain see this it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942523/step-by-step-instructions-for-installing-imagemagick-on-wamp