# Froala editor uploading

Tags: php, froala

Hi i am using froala editor and i can manage to save the content inside my database now i am just trying to upload images to my server , but i have no luck so far my only output is "Something went wrong, try again" here is my code.

```
<body>
  <div id="editor"></div>
</body>

<script>


 $(function() {
    $('#editor').froalaEditor({
      // Set the image upload URL.
      imageUploadURL: 'save.php',

      imageUploadParams: {
        id: 'my_editor'
      }
    })
  });


</script>
```

On my save.php

```
// Allowed extentions.
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

    // Get filename.
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["my_editor"]["name"]);

    // Get extension.
    $extension = end($temp);

    // An image check is being done in the editor but it is best to
    // check that again on the server side.
    // Do not use $_FILES["file"]["type"] as it can be easily forged.
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES["my_editor"]["tmp_name"]);

    if ((($mime == "image/gif")
    || ($mime == "image/jpeg")
    || ($mime == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($mime == "image/x-png")
    || ($mime == "image/png"))
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
        // Generate new random name.
        $name = sha1(microtime()) . "." . $extension;

        // Save file in the uploads folder.
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["my_editor"]["tmp_name"], getcwd() . "/upload_image/" . $name);

        // Generate response.
        $response = new StdClass;
        $response->link = "/upload_image/" . $name;
        echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));
    }
```

I am  trying to save the uploaded files into a folder inside my server named as upload_image.

Comment: Hi! Please paste the html section of the form.

Comment: Ok so the dependencies was the problem including the extension php_imagick.dll the problem now is i cannot add this on my php.ini i am using php version 5.6.

Comment: Why you cannot add it to your php.ini? Hosting provider restriction?

Comment: This link is exactly what i am experiencing but instead of wamp i am using xammp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942523/step-by-step-instructions-for-installing-imagemagick-on-wamp

Comment: Check the first answer of that post. Xampp and Wampp are nearly the same only changing the application used to control the processes. You should download the binaries for windows.

Comment: @KaoriYui could you make a screenshot of what you get into the Network tab of the developer tools in the browser console?