# php imageMagick on windows

Tags: php, dll, imagemagick

I've been trying to install imageMagick on my windows for a week, but everything I try ends up the same. Apache crashed without any error description.

The only log on apache is this:

```
[Sun May 01 16:49:14 2011] [warn] pid file D:/serv/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten --Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
```

I've also tried this configuration: 
[Installing ImageMagick extension with php/windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858439/installing-imagemagick-extension-with-php-windows)
and I get the same problem.

If I comment out this line `extension=php_imagick.dll` on `php.ini`, everything works fine.

Any ideas?

I'm working with windows 7 X64 and php 5.3.6 VC9 x86.

Comment: Just to make things clear, all the PHP dll files (librarires) are 32 bit, so if your system is 64 bit and you will still need to download and operate 32 bit ImageMagick, Apache, etc. http://www.elxsy.com/2009/07/installing-imagemagick-on-windows-and-using-with-php-imagick/

Answer (score 2):

All PHP components in this scenario must be compiled in the same bit and version of Microsoft Visual C.

If for instance you are trying to run the image magick libraries via the *`php_imagick.dll`* in the EXT sectin of the PHP setup the your versions of Apache, PHP 5, *`php_imagick.dll`* and Image Magick's install must 'ALL BE COMPILED BY THE SAME BIT and VERSION of Visual C'.

If you are running Apache 32 bit from VC9 then all the other components will have to be also compiled in VC9.  If you are running 64 bit VC8 for instance then you will have to have all matching components compiled in VC8 64 bit.

It is exactly the reason you are having this Apache problem, mismatched components.

Comment: This is opening a big can of worms. How do you compile these things? Or do you just have to try to hunt down and install compatible components?