# ImageMagick and Wamp

Tags: php, imagemagick, wamp, imagick

I know that is lot of question about it in the forum but none works!
I try to install and use ImageMagick with wamp many and many times with many versions but it didn't work.
The versions I use:
WAMP: 32 bits v2.4
Apache: v2.4.4
PHP: v5.4.16
ImageMagick: I tried lot of versions but no success.

Firstly, I tried to use this post : [Step-by-step instruction for installing imagemagick on wamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942523/step-by-step-instructions-for-installing-imagemagick-on-wamp/20599769#20599769)
I install the right ImageMagick version, install it in C:/imagick.
Then I download the .dll file for php 5.4 in http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/ and set in "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\ext\".
After I write extension=php_imagick.dll in **php.ini**.

But it didn't work, I have this message when I restart my WAMP server:
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.16/ext/php_imagick.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.

As I said, I tried many and many versions of ImageMagick and I don't know what to do now.
If someone have the time to answer me, thanks  ;)

Have a good day!

Answer (score 3):

Please see this answer already on StackOverflow:

[Installing ImageMagick extension with php/windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858439/installing-imagemagick-extension-with-php-windows)

I answered this question some time ago. This solves the specified procedure cannot be found error.