# Class Imagick Not found Error in controller

Tags: php, imagick, codeigniter-url, imagemagick-convert

I have successfully installed imagick application in windows. I am using wamp server and added extension php_imagick.dll in php.ini and file to folder name php/ext and restart the apache. But still the error of class imagick not found is shown in my code below:

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImage('mytest.pdf');
$imagick->writeImage('output.jpg');
```

can anyone help me out? I will be very grateful.

Comment: Could you check the output of `phpinfo` to check if `Imagick` is loaded and enabled correctly?

Comment: Imagick is not shown in phpinfo .. i have done all the process to install imagick but still not shown.. I dn't knw what might be the problem?

Comment: There are many articles addressing this kind of issue out there: http://www.elxsy.com/2009/07/installing-imagemagick-on-windows-and-using-with-php-imagick/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858439/installing-imagemagick-extension-with-php-windows, ...

Comment: thank you  for the url but i have tried this one too..